# Making user service invisible in the running service list

Tags: android, service

I am developing an application in which I start a service which will run in the background, 
Now I want to make this service invisible to the customers so that they can not stop it.
Is that possible?
Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not and cannot do such a thing. This will violate the basic privileges of the user over his phone and is a potential (big) security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run it. Then it won't show up and the users won't be able to stop it.